# MYSQL List of number between a range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to obtain a list of id that are in range of a second table that have ranges of ids.

First table

```
Table (ID)
1
2
...
73
```

Second table:

```
Table (Ranges)
id_lower  ||  id_upper
50               55
48               53
...
68               73
```

Result table:

```
Result Table (id)
48
49
50
51
...
```

Thanks in advance....

---

***Update requested by  FreshPrinceOfSO:***

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.id_modelo
FROM modelo M
WHERE M.id_modelo BETWEEN 
(
 SELECT G.id_modelo_inicial
 FROM general G
 WHERE G.id_modelo_inicial = M.id_modelo
)
AND
(
 SELECT G.id_modelo_final
 FROM general G
 WHERE G.id_modelo_final = M.id_modelo
);
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableA.ID
FROM
  TableA INNER JOIN Ranges
  ON TableA.ID BETWEEN Ranges.id_lower AND Ranges.id_upper
```

Answer (score 0):

select id from ID where ID.id>=Ranges.id_lower and ID.id<=Ranges.id_upper

I'm assuming the name of the column in table ID is 'id'.